# sql command where conditions

Tags: sql

How can use a condition in sql code?
when i want to compare between table to a string 
for example:

```
select userId
From tblUsers
Where userId Not Like user1;
```

`user1` is a variable which holds a string.
how can i do it?

Comment: I _guess_ that you don't know [sql-parameters](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/), do you?

Comment: Are you simply asking how to compare with a string? `userid <> 'user1'`.

Comment: how to comapre with a paramerer which is string type.                                      string str = 'sdfddf'                                                                                                     how can i compare it to userId in Where command?

Comment: What DBMS are you using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...)? And where do you execute the query from? A database tool? A program you wrote? PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @userName nvarchar(max)
SET @userName='user1'

select userId
From tblUsers
Where userId Not Like @userName;
```

Comment: thank you. If i have two comobox of userId. What command do i need to write in the second combobox so that it will not show the chosen value in the first combobox.                                      For example: there is column of id. in the first combobox i choose id=1. what i need to write so that in the second combobox 1 will not appear?

Comment: your question tags with sql, I'm surprising where from combobox comes to sql !

Comment: by the way, you need to have some sort of control(surely on UI, may be radiobutton list, checkbox list, etc...) which is **mutually exclusive** to its data source, that way you can ensure your... "in the second combobox 1 will not appear?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the diamond operator (<>) in MySQL.

```
select userId
From tblUsers
Where userId <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> Define str="%iny"
SQL> select * from emp where name like '&str';

old   1: select * from emp where name like '&str'

new   1: select * from emp where name like '%iny'


     ID NAME                                            AGE
---------- ---------------------------------------- ----------
         2 viny                                             25
         2 viny                                             25
```

have a look at this. how to user variable in sql statement.

I have declared a variable str using DEFINE command and assigned a string value.
And this variable is used in query as &str.

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @VarFilter AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'user1'
DECLARE @Istruz AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Istruz = 
'
SELECT  userId
FROM    tblUsers
WHERE   userId LIKE ''%' + @VarFilter + '%''
'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Istruz
```

Try this solution.